# Check if other features besides atlas feature are displayed in the map

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, expression, atlas

I am making an atlas in Print composer and I want to check if other features besides the atlas feature are present in the map. In the Print composer map below, the (current) atlas feature is Licab, and I want to check via expression if there are other features present in the map besides Licab.

[image: Map atlas feature question]

How can I check via expression if the map contains other features besides the current atlas feature?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to check this? Inside the map frame you can use @map_extent variable, but this one wont work for example in a text box. Outside you can use item_variables('Map 1')['map_extent'] to get the extent. You tagged qgis-2, which version do you use?

Comment: @MrXsquared: I created a text label below the map. I want to insert an expression in the label to return TRUE or FALSE if there are other features (besides the atlas feature) displayed in the extent of that map. I am using version 2.18.14.

Answer (score 5):

Couldnt find a solution for QGIS 2 using only expressions, I guess a custom function to get the current map extent is needed for this version (similar to `item_variables('Map 1')['map_extent']` in QGIS 3).
However, just in case someone is looking for a **solution in QGIS 3**, here is an expression:

```sql
if( 
 intersects( -- check if atlas layer and map extent intersect (by doing the following:)
  aggregate( -- to create a geometrycollection,
   layer:=@atlas_layername, -- get the desired layer and
   aggregate:='collect', -- collect
   expression:=$geometry, -- its geometry
   filter:=$id<>@atlas_featureid -- except for the current atlas feature
  ), -- closing aggregate()
  transform( -- transform
   item_variables('Map 1')['map_extent'], -- the geometry of the map extent
   item_variables('Map 1')['map_crs'], -- from the map extents crs
   layer_property(@atlas_layername,'crs') -- to the layers crs
  ) -- closing transform()
 ) -- closing intersects()
=1, -- if both geometries intersect
'TRUE', -- display true as string
'FALSE' -- and if not display false as string
) -- closing if()
```

Just change `'Map 1'` to the name of the layout map you are using

Example:

[image]

Explanation: The expression aggregates the atlas layer (except for the current atlas feature) to one single geometry. Then it checks wheter this collection intersects with the current map-extent. If it does (and therefore at least one other feature is visible), it returns the string 'True'.

Comment: The aim of @JAT86's question doesn't seem to be checking **all** features but only to check whether there are **some** in the map extent. But i may be wrong ...

Comment: @Snaileater thats exactly what the expression does, just in the wrong version

Comment: You aggregate **all** features but the atlas feature ... don't you ?

Comment: Yes, to check if at least one feature of the layer is inside the current map extent (except for the current atlas geometry)